# Questions Regarding DoS

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, denial-of-service

I have a few questions i still haven`t been able to get an answer to.

1. If someone DoS you, do it affect all computers connected to the router or just the computer that is being attacked? For example: You have a server on your computer connected to a open port 78452 so people can connect to the server. And then someone DoS that specifik port to take down your server. Do that DoS affect all computers using the router or just my computer?
2. If someone DoS you, is there a way to redirect those packets into the void so these packets go into nowhere.?
3. Is there a easy way to change your IP adress on your router? Lets say someone DoS the IP: 1.1.1.1.1 and then i change the ip to: 2.2.2.2.2 to get rid of the DoS attack?

Answer (score 2):

Curious about the downvotes, so heres my response:

1. Depends on the exact method used to DOS. For state-attacks like syn-floods, no, since it just fills up the servers state-tables, but for traffic saturation attacks like DNS amplification attacks, yes, all internal machines would have to fight to get bandwidth from the router.
2. Once again, depends on the type of attack. for traffic based floods, no, only an upstream entity can do that, but for state based attacks, yes. The technique is called [bucket filtering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Token_bucket_filter). When correctly configured, they can drop packets into digital oblivion.
3. Yes, but you would be DOSing yourself, since no one could connect to you. you would have done the attackers job for them.  Either way however, you would have to configure legal IP addresses (so you could never use 2.2.2.2.2).

   I expect a justification for any downvotes.

Comment: I think they downvoted me because of my bad english, but i don't care about stats, just trying to help. Anyway , you explained perfectly, so Upvotin you :)

Answer (score 0):

1. No. The other computers will be fine. Although if you are talking about some cheap consumer router, he might freeze.
2. There are many scripts for that depending on what is server serving. You can also try to close the port.
3. (Depends on your router..) Local or External IP?.. Either way you will lose connection to the server.

(If the DoS attack is successful you will be denied of service so you will have to get involved physically :)